# Why do many SQL Server severity 10 errors actually seem severe?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

BOL states that SQL Server level 10 messages are "Informational messages that return status information or report errors that are not severe."

However these errors seem severe and not informational:

- 2540 - `The system cannot self repair this error.`
- 2745 - `Process ID %d has raised user error %d, severity %d. SQL Server is terminating this process.`
- 3606 - `Arithmetic overflow occurred.`
- 3607 - `Division by zero occurred.`

These are just a few of the ones that seem more than just information.  They were taken using the following query:

```
SELECT
message_id,
language_id,
severity,
is_event_logged,
text
FROM sys.messages
WHERE 
language_id = 1033
AND
severity = 10
```

Why do many SQL Server severity 10 errors actually seem severe?

Comment: @Mitch: I guess he is asking why he is getting non-severe (in his perspective) messages when he quired for severe ones. Or "the server's definition of severity is not well-defined".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The severity in sys.messages is not the actual severity they are raised with.

Comment: Interesting. Is there any further documentation/explanation on this behavior? I take it you're not talking about http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164086.aspx - "For compatibility reasons, the Database Engine converts severity 10 to severity 0 before returning the error information to the calling application."

Answer (score 1):

Severity can be subjective, in your examples,
- 3606 - Arithmetic overflow occurred.
- 3607 - Division by zero occurred.

Well, these may mean ok to you but to the server, this might snowballed into something severe up to your App's business logic.

Nevertheless, I do agree that some/a lot of the messages (severity aside) are not clear/vaue/ambiguous.

Comment: Those two specifically I would consider severe errors.  There are counterparts for both of these  at the 16 level, which I understand is the most common error.  Any idea what makes a level 10 and a level 16 divide-by-zero error different?

Comment: Well, you might want to evaluate Remus' answer which I feel explained the issue. +1 for him. : )